# Child Object is not Synching across network - Unity networking

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have a player(camera controller) object which consist of **three child object**(walk cam, fly cam). I am my spawning player as I start (and activating only fly cam) or join game. But the problem is my child object(Fly cam) movement is not showing on the network while its locally moving perfectly.

**I have done this so far**

1. I have  added network transform and network identity to parent 
   *(Not worked)*
2. I have  added network transform and network identity and network transform child (with cam fly assignment) to parent.*(Not worked)* 
   Not work
3. I have  added network transform and network identity and network transform child (with cam fly assignment) to parent.*(Not worked)*
4. I have  added network transform and network identity and network transform child (with cam fly assignment) to parent and network identity and network transform to child(fly cam).*(Not worked)*
5. I have  added network transform and network identity to parent and network identity and network transform to child(fly cam).*(Not worked)*

**remember: my parent object is not moving**